# How to listen for an AUDIO file using Python and Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, http, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html5-audio

Full disclosure, I'm fairly new to **Python** and **Selenium Webdriver**.

I am expanding a small automation project that I've been working on. I have an in-browser chat window that, when a message is received, a file titled '`chime.mp3`' will play to notify the user of a new message.

To verify the success that this audio file has played, I will need to verify that the file was called or requested via HTTP request, i.e. https://usr/bin/webapps/chime.mp3

Is there a module I could import in python, or a webdriver technique to listen for this file being requested?

Or is there a known way to verify audio files play on a certain event?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no built-in functionality in Selenium (or Python) that you could use for that.

While you can't easily verify that the sound as *actually* been played however, you can easily verify whether your site has instructed the browser to play the file. Most likely, your site will use the [HTML5 audio tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) to actually play the file, and you can check for that:

#### Example (Java)

```
WebElement audio = driver.findElement(By.tagName("audio")); // make sure any audio tag is there

// ... or ...

WebElement audio = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//audio/source[contains(@src, 'chime.mp3')]/..")); // make sure an audio tag is there that refers to chime.mp3

assertTrue(Boolean.parseBoolean(audio.getAttribute("ended"))); // make sure the audio tag has played at least once
```